# How to extract the Zeroth index value from list containg the numpy array

Tags: python-3.x

I have list

```
[219]
[346 347]
[474 475]
[602]
[730]
[1114]
[1242]
[1369 1370]
[1497]
[1625]
[2392 2393]
[2520]
[3288]
[3415 3416]
[3543]
[3671]
[4311]
[4438 4439]
[4566]
[5206]
[5334]
[5461 5462]
...]
```

each element is a numpy array.
I want to extract the only first element in all array (some of them containing two).
I have tried following code :

```
c=[]
for b in range(len(a)):
    c.append(np.array(a[b][0][0]))
```

It is showing the following error:

```
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

If I tried individually extract it is giving me an answer:

```
a[0][0][0]=91
a[1][0][0]=219
a[2][0][0]=346
...so on.
```

I tried old stack overflow answers also..not working.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

As I could see you have a list of NumPy arrays, so you don't have to access the elements using 3 indexing. It'll work fine if you use only 2 indices. And I think that is the reason for the error too.

Following code works well for me to extract the 0th element from each NumPy array present in the list:-

```
c = []
for i in range(len(a)):
  c.append(np.array(a[i][0]))
```

I got output like this when I printed c:-

```
[array(219),
 array(346),
 array(474),
 array(602),
 array(730),
 array(1114),
 array(1242),
 array(1369),
 array(1497),
 array(1625),
 array(2392),
 array(2520),
 array(3288),
 array(3415),
 array(3543),
 array(3671),
 array(4311),
 array(4438),
 array(4566),
 array(5206),
 array(5334),
 array(5461)]
```

Comment: What output you're getting?

Comment: I am getting the same element as in 'a' in 'c'.

Comment: Can you send or attach the complete code that you're implementing?